# How does the following sentence should be read?

Tags: word-usage

[image]

*The final three months of the year see a dramatic fall in precipitation, to a low of about 10mm in December, **and a steady drop in temperatures back to the January average**.*

the passage is from the writting sample considered to be 9 band which describes the climograph given above.  My question is that, does the final clause in bold have to be considered along with the begining part of the passage *(The final three months of the year see)* and as a result it should be read and construed as ; *"The final three months of the year see a steady drop in temperature back to the January"* ?

Actually my aim is to determine what the exact role of "back to" here is? Is it verb of the subject - "a steady drop" or adverb modifier of "a steady drop" ? Looking forward to having your responses.

p.s - Don't know how to tag this question so it would be appreciated if anyone edit it and add releated tags.

Comment: **How should...?** (not *does...should*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a compound direct object

```
see 
-> a fall 
and
-> a drop
```

**drop** is modified by a prepositional phrase **in temperatures**.

The phrase **back to the January average** can be construed as another prepositional phrase also modifying the noun **drop** or the noun-phrase **a steady drop**.

Compare:

> ...a long walk **back to camp**

There is no verb in that phrase, so I wouldn't call **back** an adverb, though it is often called one.

Two prepositional phrases:

> ...a difficult climb over loose rock **up to the peak**

Prepositional phrases can express motion and direction.

Comment: so would it be wrong to rephrased it like  ; *Last 3 months see a steady drop in temperatures which ultimaly the figures return to its initial level* ?

Comment: That sentence would be ungrammatical, because of the combination of the relative **which** and the new subject **the figures**. The relative occupies the place of the subject.  *... drop in temperatures which ultimately return to their initial level*.

Comment: **Temperatures** is the antecedent of **which**. **drop** is not the antecedent of **which** in  *drop in temperatures which ultimately return to their initial level.*. Note that it says **their** not **its**.

Comment: implication was the rephrased seentence

Comment: Your rephrased sentence is confusing the antecedent of the relative **which**, and thus you have a number-agreement error with the pronoun. See my comment above.

Comment: *to drop back* means to return (via motion downwards or backwards ) to a previous position.  The idea is "return".

Comment: so you see *drop back* together as averb phrase ? I thought that **drop** should be taken as seperately.

Comment: **drop** is not a verb but a noun here.  Don't confuse the paraphrase with the original.  Compare "a long walk back to camp". One moment, you're asking about the sense; in the question, you're asking about the grammatical role. You keep bouncing back and forth. The temperatures are returning to their initial level.  **back** is a preposition expressing the idea of "return". In conjunction with **drop**, the return is via downward  motion, when **a drop** means "a fall".

Comment: I knew that by knowing grammatical role I'd be able to determine exact meaning of clause containing **drop in temperature back to the Jan. average**

Comment: It is a prepositional phrase which, in conjunction with the noun it modifies, expresses a return via downward motion to a previous position.

Comment: when read first I believed that the last clause in question would be viewed as seperately regardless of **final 3 months see**.    **(a steady drop in temperature)** is the subject and  **(back to)** is the verb, then I realized that it could be read together with **final 3 months see**  and in this case meaning would be totally different . That ambiguity lead me to ask.

Comment: You can understand **back** as an adverb. But since there's no verb involved, **a steady drop** being a noun-phrase, I would call it a preposition complemented by a prepositional phrase. **back to** is definitely not a verb.  **a steady drop in temperature** is an object of verb **see**, not the subject.